# When I inspect Amazon I see Amazon wrap header, main and footer tags inside div. Why? If we have semantics tags so why use div to wrap these things?

Tags: html, header, footer, program-entry-point

When I inspect Amazon I see Amazon wrap header, main and footer tags  inside div. Why?  If we have semantics tags so why use div to wrap these things? And can we use semantic tag without wrap inside div?
I just want to know why these things use in this way?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6itWA.jpg)

Comment: There are many reasons why things may have been done in a way that doesn't fit with what you consider modern best practice. It might be something as simple as the page was designed before support for semantic tags was widespread. Or maybe the programmer was in a hurry that day. Or the developer had been in a pressured job for years and hadn't caught up. Or... If you want to know why that job was done that way, ask the people who actually did it.